# How to fix PrimeNG dropdown style issue?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG 1.0.0-rc.4 (although had the same issue with earlier version). The dropdown always displays its dropdown pointer to the right. A rollover shows the associated button is also to the right. Tried it with different themes with same result. What's going on and how do I fix it?

[image: PrimeNG DropDown]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap styling with it? I've seen this issue using bootstrap 3.x with primeng

Comment: The attached pic shows omega, but I did try using bootstrap and got the same thing. I did manage to fix the issue by changing margin-left setting in.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-trigger .fa style, but I'm not sure why I would have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be that you better use the grid system provided by PrimeNG, because you maybe solve that specific issue now, but it's so probable that you'll find more like that on the way. Here's the documentation about it: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/responsive

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using the PrimeNG but am thinking of giving it a try. I'm not sure why using it would have any impact on a control styling issue though.

Comment: That's because bootstrap applies its styles over those controls and primeng does the same, so you have both mixing up and this is more noticeable with some controls than others, so you'll have to be dealing with that.

Comment: You're right. Bootstrap css does conflict with primeNG css. Thanks.

Comment: New Bootstrap theme is on the way. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1512